# How to give ID to other controller: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to give an id of "paper model" to "schedules model" and create a note_id.
However an error message "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" shows.
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

papers/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Go to Schedule", new_schedule_path(id: paper.id) %>
```

routes.rb

```
get '/schedules/new/:id', to: 'schedules#new', as: :schedules_new
```

schedules_controller

```
class ActionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_schedule, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
   def new
    @schedule = Schedule.new
   end
   def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
    @schedule.user_id = current_user.id
    @schedule.note_id = params[:id]
    if @schedule.save
      redirect_to schedules_path, notice: "A schedule was saved!"
    end
   end
  def index
      @schedules = Schedule.all
  end
  def update
  end

  def delete
  end

Private
  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(:note_id, :user_id, :params[:id])
  end

  def set_schedule
          @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

params
=> "31", "controller"=>"schedules", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false>

Comment: the `params` that send from front-end includes only an `id`. That why it raises an error when you call `params.require(:schedule)...`. You dont need this line `@schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)` and the `schedule_params` call in `create` action.

Comment: Nermin is correct. But I think your issue is that you're trying to access the params hash inside the permit part of the strong params. Once inside the permit method, you're already inside the params hash, so it would just be `:id`, not `params[:id]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem as follow.

Controller:

```
def new
 @schedule = Schedule.new
 @schedule.note_id = params[:id]
end
def create
 @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
 @schedule.user_id = current_user.id
 if @schedule.save
   redirect_to schedules_path, notice: "A schedule was saved!"
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
.
.
.
Private
def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(:note_id, :user_id)
end
```

Add into View

```
<%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => @schedule.note_id %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not even using *shedule_params* values, as you override them afterwards ......

Then you could create empty `Schedule` object and then assign values ...

```
def create
   @schedule = Schedule.new
   @schedule.user_id = current_user.id
   @schedule.note_id = params[:id]
   if @schedule.save
     redirect_to schedules_path, notice: "A schedule was saved!"
   end
end
```

Or if I am correct with your relations, it could be also

```
def create
   @schedule = current_user.schedules.new
   @schedule.note_id = params[:id]
   if @schedule.save
     redirect_to schedules_path, notice: "A schedule was saved!"
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I already tried this, but an other error shows:undefined method `permit' for "create":String... I think params[:id] was saved as string but not integer, so this message was shown.

Comment: Can you past whole *schedules_controller* ?

Comment: Thanks Nermin, but if I modify my schedule_controller, a new error message shows "undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass" with both methods...